# I can't get images to the same size [HTML/CSS]

Tags: html, css, image-scaling

I have two pictures that have 512px in height and 512px in width. Whatsoever the plus symbol is bigger than the shutdown button.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="logout">
    <a href="someLink"> 
      <img name="logout" alt="logout" src="red_shutdown.png">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="plus-symbol">
    <img name="plus" alt="create-post" src="plus-symbol.png">
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.logout {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: 1.32%;
  border: 0;
}
div.plus-symbol {

  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: 1.32%;
  border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make the parent tag of 512*512. then just make the image to be
`width:100%; height:100%;`

Also check from inspect if the images are overflowing or not if yes then `overflow:hidden`

Comment: or just set img height and widt 100% and max-height and max-width 512px

Answer (score 0):

If this variant doens't work, tell me please.

```
<style>
   img {
      width: 512px !important;
      height: 512px !important;
   }
</style>
```

And you can also put a class to the

Just like that:

```
<div class="logout">
   <a href="someLink"> 
      <img name="logout" class="img_icon" alt="logout" src="red_shutdown.png">
   </a>
</div>

<div class="plus-symbol">
   <img name="plus" class="img_icon" alt="create-post" src="plus-symbol.png">
</div>

<style>
   .img_icon {
      width: 512px !important;
      height: 512px !important;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: Theres no need to use `!important` here. In addition, you should avoid using `!importan` anyway.

Comment: Ok. Ok, I use `!important` not any time I apply the style